# Inheritance in Rails databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, inheritance

I am planning a database diagram for my Rails project.
I have the following entities: Answer (inherits from Post), Question (also inherits from Post) and Comment.
A Comment belongs to either an Answer or a Question.
How will I go on doing this?

I have thought of creating a Posts table, while having Questions and Answers tables, which has an entry for each question and each answer. Then I would have a table connecting Comments and Posts.
I feel this solution is not clean and not generic enough.

**What is the best and most efficient way to do this?**

**EDIT**:
I'm not interested in a STI (single table inheritance) solution. We are looking for an efficient solution, since this will (hopefully) be a large project with many posts.

Comment: @Hizki What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 3):

The default Rails inheritance model is Single Table Inheritance and is the simplest, cleanest, most generic, and most database-agnostic thing to do.

It is accomplished simply by having Answer and Question inherit from Post.  Then you create a posts table that has all the fields you want in Post, Answer, and Question.

Single Table Inheritance isn't the most space-efficient technique because all rows in the posts table will have *all* the fields of Post, Answer, and Question.  But it is conventional and if you run into space issues down the road you will be in a good position to migrate to a more scalable data model (like Multiple Table Inheritance).  And Single Table Inheritance is efficient in the sense that it only requires a single query to find a post by ID, where in other data models there may be an extra query to find what table (post, question, answer) the post is in.

As for connecting Comments and Posts, you can use a `belongs_to` relation in the Comment model that points to Post and a `has_many` relation in the Post model that points to Comment.  (You will need to add a post_id integer field to the comments table to get this to work).

cf. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

You will also want to add an index for comments on post_id for quickly querying all the comments for a post:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html .

Comment: I don't think it's good practice to start with a non scalable solution which will probably be replaced later on... And then, I would be stuck with the same question... so...

Comment: Single Table Inheritance is not "non scalable," it just may add columns to the database.  The reason I advise Single Table Inheritance is that it's the conventional way to do inheritance in Rails.

Comment: You wrote that maybe somewhere down the road I'll want to "migrate to a more scalable data model". Why not find THAT solution from the beginning?

Comment: No two apps scale alike, and every optimization comes with tradeoffs.

*If* you run out of space down the road, by having followed conventions you will be in a good place to then optimize :)

Answer (score 2):

You should weigth using polymorphic associations over using STI.

For instance, in your case, you should question if you really want to have a superclass Post. Maybe Questions and answers should not belong in the same iherarchy and maybe both should be connected to the class comment through a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). That is: Maybe they should be marked as 'Commentable'

Comment: sorry. This was a mistype. I fixed it. I was actually trying to advise you to conssider polymorphic associations. These can be easily indexed (composed key on id and type) and you are able to have everything in separate tables. It's not a matter of being scalable or non-scalable. It has more to do with possibly wishing that the database is more normalized than STI allows.